# How to read a csv file, individually for further processing

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to read a csv file line by line. But it's proving to be a bit more difficult then first anticipated.

**The Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import glob
import os

file_dir=os.getcwd()
files_2=glob.glob(file_dir)

m_class="ABC"
m_id="123"
device=m_class+"-"+m_id

with open('output_temp.csv', 'w') as output_temp:
    for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), device+'*.log')):
        #print "----\nFILE NAME: " + filename
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            content = f.readlines()
            if content:
                mycontent=str("".join(content))
                #print mycontent
                output_temp.write(str(mycontent))

counter=1
with open('output_temp.csv', 'r') as f: 
    content = f.readlines()
    print "Line: " + str(counter) + " data: " + str(content)
    counter=counter+1
```

**output_temp.csv file:**

```
1464557866.4111354
1464561244.9223452
1464506206.4268115
1464507324.3743494
1464491791.4750218
1464492017.1200309
1464560723.4278536
1464560838.5569682
1464578213.2567956
1464580860.4225895
1464534128.2530715
1464545504.5457716
1464603405.5002685
1464610938.5988958
1464560390.4099076
1464579888.7111971
1464591413.4147444
1464595286.6162462
1464548255.5633001
1464548400.8739398
1464596402.442414
1464603613.2534776
1464523008.4462287
1464524100.9739816
1464389395.6676936
1464389586.7012687
1464542283.2585688
1464548192.5785992
```

**The Terminal Output:**

```
Line: 1 data: ['1464557866.4111354\n', '1464561244.9223452\n', '1464506206.4268115\n', '1464507324.3743494\n', '1464491791.4750218\n', '1464492017.1200309\n', '1464560723.4278536\n', '1464560838.5569682\n', '1464578213.2567956\n', '1464580860.4225895\n', '1464534128.2530715\n', '1464545504.5457716\n', '1464603405.5002685\n', '1464610938.5988958\n', '1464560390.4099076\n', '1464579888.7111971\n', '1464591413.4147444\n', '1464595286.6162462\n', '1464548255.5633001\n', '1464548400.8739398\n', '1464596402.442414\n', '1464603613.2534776\n', '1464523008.4462287\n', '1464524100.9739816\n', '1464389395.6676936\n', '1464389586.7012687\n', '1464542283.2585688\n', '1464548192.5785992\n']
```

**Q:** I would like to print each of the lines in the csv file independently so I can do some manipulations on the values, append some values, and do some concatenations. How can I print each line individually as in the `output_temp.csv` file

NB: I am new to Python.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with this code:

```
counter=1
with open('output_temp.csv', 'r') as f: 
    content = f.readlines()
    print "Line: " + str(counter) + " data: " + str(content)
    counter=counter+1
```

`content` here is a list with all the lines. Iterate through `content` and `.strip()` the data of newlines and you should be fine:

```
# No need a counter
with open('output_temp.csv', 'r') as f: 
    content = f.readlines()
    for count, data in enumerate(content):
        print "Line: " + str(count+1) + " data: " + data.strip("\n")
```

Output:

```
Line: 1 data: 1464557866.4111354
Line: 2 data: 1464561244.9223452
Line: 3 data: 1464506206.4268115
Line: 4 data: 1464507324.3743494
Line: 5 data: 1464491791.4750218
Line: 6 data: 1464492017.1200309
Line: 7 data: 1464560723.4278536
Line: 8 data: 1464560838.5569682
Line: 9 data: 1464578213.2567956
Line: 10 data: 1464580860.4225895
Line: 11 data: 1464534128.2530715
Line: 12 data: 1464545504.5457716
Line: 13 data: 1464603405.5002685
Line: 14 data: 1464610938.5988958
Line: 15 data: 1464560390.4099076
Line: 16 data: 1464579888.7111971
Line: 17 data: 1464591413.4147444
Line: 18 data: 1464595286.6162462
Line: 19 data: 1464548255.5633001
Line: 20 data: 1464548400.8739398
Line: 21 data: 1464596402.442414
Line: 22 data: 1464603613.2534776
Line: 23 data: 1464523008.4462287
Line: 24 data: 1464524100.9739816
Line: 25 data: 1464389395.6676936
Line: 26 data: 1464389586.7012687
Line: 27 data: 1464542283.2585688
Line: 28 data: 1464548192.5785992
```

It seems that you aren't that familiar with the basics of loops in Python. Read the more on for loops [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) and more on `enumerate` [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate). Remember, when in doubt, Google or Pydoc!

Comment: Thanks for that, but how would I be able to subtract one from `str(data.strip("\n"))`? for example `prev=1464557866.4111354 - 1.0`

Comment: @3kstc You could convert it to an `float` then back to a `str`. e.g. `str(float(data.strip("\n")) - 1.0)`

Answer (score 0):

Using the csv module in python you could do this easily. The example below prints the csv file line by line.

```
import csv
import os

os.chdir("/Users/xaviermerino/Desktop")

with open('csvExample.csv') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    for row in reader:
        print row[0]
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module. Create a [reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) to parse the file and a [writer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) to write the new file.